# Is there a way to get the value from a text filed in a table view cell to use it in another table view cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, cell

I'm building an iOS e-commerce app which sells shoe products. This question is about the Checkout screen which is a `UITableViewController` to collect billing information of the user and save it in `Firebase`.

Below `UITableViewController` contains two custom `UITableView` cells. The first cell contains some text fields to get billing information(Email, Card Number, Expiration Date and CVC) from the user, while the second cell below that contains a submit button to save them in `Firebase`.

My requirement is to get the billing information from the user and save it in Firebase when clicking the Submit button. (Text fields and submit button are in two separate `UITableView` cells)

Could you please help me with this. Please find below code snippets.

**CheckoutViewController.swift**

```
class CheckoutTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    // MARK: - Properties

    var shoes : [Shoe]! {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    // MARK: - Structs

    struct Storyboard {
        static let billingInfoCell = "billingInfoCell"
        static let submitButtonCell = "submitButtonCell"
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    // MARK: - Data source

     override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.billingInfoCell, for: indexPath) as! BillingInfoTableViewCell // Contains billing information text fields
            return cell
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.submitButtonCell, for: indexPath) as! SubmitButtonTableViewCell // Contains Submit button
            return cell
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }

}
```

**BillingInfoTableViewCell.swift**

```
class BillingInfoTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - IBOutlets

    @IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cardNumberTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var expirationDataTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var securityNumberTextField: UITextField!


}
```

**SubmitButtonTableViewCell.swift**

```
class SubmitButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    // MARK: - IBActions
    @IBAction func submitOrderButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print("Submit button tapped!")
    }

}
```

Comment: use a static array to save information about billing when user completed editing text in all textfields on submit button click

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow the below steps.

Make the outlet of `UITableView`

```
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
```

Make static `UITableviewCell`

```
lazy var cellBillingInfo = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.billingInfoCell) as! BillingInfoTableViewCell
lazy var cellSubmit = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.submitButtonCell) as! SubmitButtonTableViewCell
```

Add target for submit button as below.

```
cellSubmit.btnSumit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submitOrderButtonTapped(_:).tou), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Define submit button method

```
@objc func submitOrderButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(cellBillingInfo.emailTextField.text)
        print(cellBillingInfo.cardNumberTextField.text)
        print(cellBillingInfo.expirationDataTextField.text)
        print(cellBillingInfo.securityNumberTextField.text)
}
```

**Final Code:**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    // MARK: - Properties
    
    lazy var cellBillingInfo = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.billingInfoCell) as! BillingInfoTableViewCell
    lazy var cellSubmit = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Storyboard.submitButtonCell) as! SubmitButtonTableViewCell
    
    var shoes : [Shoe]! {
        didSet {
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: - Structs
    
    struct Storyboard {
        static let billingInfoCell = "billingInfoCell"
        static let submitButtonCell = "submitButtonCell"
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    // MARK: - Data source
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 2
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        
        if indexPath.row == 0 {
            return cellBillingInfo
        } else if indexPath.row == 1 {
            cellSubmit.btnSumit.addTarget(self, action: #selector(submitOrderButtonTapped(_:).tou), for: .touchUpInside)
            return cellSubmit
        } else {
            return UITableViewCell()
        }
    }
    
    @objc func submitOrderButtonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
        print(cellBillingInfo.emailTextField.text)
        print(cellBillingInfo.cardNumberTextField.text)
        print(cellBillingInfo.expirationDataTextField.text)
        print(cellBillingInfo.securityNumberTextField.text)
    }
}

class SubmitButtonTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var btnSumit: UIButton!
}
```

Comment: Welcome and glad to hear! Glad to hear